# Delete a record in a Random File in Vb6

Tags: vb6, record

I'm trying to manage a quite-small DataBase with Vb6 and NotePad.
I collect all the record in Random into the Notepad File (.dat).
I use the Get and Put command for getting the record I stored and insert the newest.
Now I'd like to have the possibility to DELETE a record I entered (maybe the latest).
I tought that:

```
Delete #FileNumber1, LatestRec, MyRec
```

was a good chance to get it.
LatestRec is the number of the latest record (ex: 5 means the 5th). 
MyRec is my record variable.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The Delete statement you note above doesn't apply for random access files. Unfortunately, VB6 Random Access files provide no direct mechanism for record deletion, primarily because deletion leads to a rat's nest of other issues, such as file contraction (filling the empty space), fragmentation (unused empty space), to name a couple. If you truly need to delete a record, about the only option you have is to copy all the *other* records to a temporary file, delete the old file, and rename the temp file to the "original" name - and, sadly, that's right from Microsoft.

One thing you can do, which I'll admit up front isn't ideal, is to add a "deleted" field to your random-access file, defaulting to 0, but changing to true, 1, or some other relevant value, to indicate that the record is no longer valid.

You could even get into writing routines to reuse deleted records, but if you're getting into file semantics that much, you might be better served by considering a move of the application to a more robust database environment, such as SQL Server.

****EDIT***:*Here is a very rough/crude/untested chunk of sample VB6 code that shows how you would delete/add a record with the "deleted field" concept I described above..caveat that tweaks might be needed to get this code perfect, but the point is to illustrate the concept for you:

```
Type SampleRecord
   UserID As Long
   lastName As String * 25
   firstName As String * 25
   Deleted As Boolean
End Type
' This logically deletes a record by setting
' its "Deleted" member to True
Sub DeleteRecord(recordId As Long)

   Dim targetRecord As SampleRecord
   Dim fileNumber As Integer

   fileNumber = FreeFile

   Open "SampleFile" For Random As fileNumber Len = LenB(SampleRecord)

   Get fileNumber, recordId, targetRecord

   targetRecord.Deleted = True

   Put #fileNumber, recordId, targetRecord

   Close #fileNumber

End Sub

Sub AddRecord(lastName As String, firstName As String)

   Dim newRecord As SampleRecord
   Dim fileNumber As Integer
   Dim newRecordPosition As Long


   newRecord.firstName = firstName
   newRecord.lastName = lastName
   newRecord.Deleted = False
   newRecord.UserID = 123 ' assume an algorithm for assigning this value

   fileNumber = FreeFile
   Open "SampleFile" For Random As fileNumber Len = LenB(SampleRecord)
   newRecordPosition = LOF(fileNumber) / LenB(SampleRecord) + 1
   Put #fileNumber, newRecordPosition, newRecord
   Close #fileNumber

End Sub
```

Comment: How can I set 0 and 1 to records?

Comment: I would make a "structure" or "record" of the layout of your database, and add the field there. If you need to delete a record, use GET to fetch the record into a variable of that "record", set its "Deleted" field to 1, then "PUT" the record back to the file. You would need to account for that value as you use records in the rest of your application.